# Java Web Service Certifcate Checking

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I have developed a webservice in Java. This webservice will be called by other servers, which will have been assigned a certificate from us.

Now I don't know much about SSL, and I have been given a

- Root CA
- Issuing CA

And I need to check that the certificate provided (when the webservice is called), is "a chain from the root ca". What would be the best way to go about this?

I've read a lot about trustmanagers and keystores, but it's quite confusing and I haven't found anything which is very similar to my question.

I also need to extract a line from the certificate (the 'issued to' field) to use in my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have been given a
>
> - Root CA
> - Issuing CA
>
> I need to check that the certificate provided (when the webservice is called), is "a chain from the root ca"

Just put those files, and no others, into your truststore. No code required. See the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

> I also need to extract a line from the certificate (the 'issued to' field) to use in my application

You mean dynamically? when the peer connects? You can get the certificate from the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` request attribute, and you then just use the certificate API to get the IssuerDN.

Comment: Ah that's easier then I thought. And I'm assuming any other client which tries connecting using another cert not from our root one, will automatically not be able to connect?

Comment: Correct. If the server is set to require an SSL certificate and it isn't signed by something in the truststore the connection will be terminated before any application code even runs.